# Why I can't do git push even if I did git reset?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push my latest local changes, but an error occurs.

```
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://******************.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

## What I Did

- `git pull`

Always `Already up to date.` returned.

- `git reset --hard`

`HEAD is now at ****** COMMITNAME` returned. This is correct.

- `git fetch` and `git merge`

`fatal: No current branch.` returned when `git merge` called.

## What I want to do

I want to do just below.

```
git add .
git commit -m ""
git push origin dev
```

Now, `git push origin dev` is the problem.

---

I have no idea what should I do. Anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your local dev branch is not ahead of the remote dev branch, pull and merge the changes before pushing. This can be done with rebase.

```
git pull origin dev --rebase
git push -f origin dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but but still can't push.
After executing `git pull origin dev --rebase`, `HEAD is up to date.` is shown.
And after doing `git push -f origin dev`, `Everything up-to-date` is show.

I did `git add` and `git commit` before pushing.

Comment: @yolo Make sure you're on the right branch. Do a `git checkout dev` and push it?